# canonicalization of xml in xamarin shared project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

Is there canonicalization api available to be used in xamarin shared project? If not what is the best way to implement xml canonicalization in cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

You could reference to the MS docs. It performs how to use XAML to define Xamarin.Forms user interfaces.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/

You could install XAML Styler extension. I use it to format XAML source by sorting the attributes based on the importance.

```
Visual Studio> Extensions> Manage Extensions> XAML Styler
```